# Java split stops at white space while using | as delimiter

Tags: java, split

I am splitting a String with split() but I don't know why it stops when it reaches a whitespace. Here is the code:

```
String a = "R|1|^^^fieldname1|18.8H |||||||||";

String[] b = a.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
also tried
String[] b = a.split("\\|");

System.out.println("Array length :"+b.length);
```

Output is : 4

I could not find a reason behind this please suggest me what am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the javadoc :

> String.split(String pattern, int limit)
>
> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. **If n is non-positive** then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. **If n is zero**
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

You can see the code of split :

```
public String[] split(String regex) {
    return split(regex, 0);
}
```

This is normal that the lqst empty values are removed, the limit is 0.

If you pass -1, this will take every empty value. No right triming is done on the empty cells.

```
String a = "R|1|^^^fieldname1|18.8H|||||||||";
String[] b = a.split("\\|", -1);
System.out.println(b.length);
```

With an output of

```
 13
```

Comment: This is the cleanest approch, this is the correct use of String.split as the doc says

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation of `split` it says:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument
>   `{@link#split(String, int) split}` method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero.  Trailing empty strings are therefore not
>   included in the resulting array.

Since you have empty `String`s between your last `|`s they are not included in the result.

If you try this:

```
String a = "R|1|^^^fieldname1|18.8H | | | | | | | | |";

String[] b = a.split("\\|");

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(b));
```

The result will be:

```
[R, 1, ^^^fieldname1, 18.8H ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will it be possible to call b[4] or other blank values with index higher than 3.

Comment: Yes. Try it out. You can Copy-paste it into your IDE.